# Move multiple elements (based on criteria) to end of list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have the following 2 Python lists:

```
main_l = ['Temp_Farh', 'Surface', 'Heater_back', 'Front_Press',
'Lateral_Cels', 'Gauge_Finl','Gauge_Relay','Temp_Throw','Front_JL']
hlig = ['Temp', 'Lateral', 'Heater','Front']
```

I need to move elements from `main_l` to the end of the list if they contain strings listed in `hlig`.

Final version of `main_l` should look like this:

```
main_l = ['Surface', 'Gauge_Finl','Gauge_Relay', 'Temp_Farh', 'Heater_back', 'Front_Press',
'Lateral_Cels', 'Temp_Throw','Front_JL']
```

**My attempt:**

I first try to find if the list `main_l` contains elements with a substring listed in the 2nd list `hlig`. Here is the way I am doing this:

```
`found` = [i for e in hlig for i in main_l if e in i]
```

`found` is a sublist of `main_l`. The problem is: now that I have this list, I do not know how to select the elements that do NOT contain the substrings in `hlig`. If I could do this, then I could add them to a list `not_found` and then I could concatenate them like this: `not_found + found` - and this would give me what I want.

**Question:**

Is there a way to move matching elements to end of the list `main_l`?

Comment: Is it always the case that the elements in the second list are prefixes separated by an underscore?

Comment: No. Sometimes, they are not prepended with the underscore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could sort `main_l` using whether each element contains a string from hlig as a key:

```
main_l.sort(key=lambda x: any(term in x for term in hlig))
```

Comment: You can remove the square brackets for slightly less visual noise and to enable `any()` to short-circuit.

Comment: The first solution is stable.  No need for the second one.

Comment: Whoops, I assumed it wasn't. Corrected.

Comment: Huh? When I try `print main_l.sort(key=lambda x: any(term in x for term in hlig))` I am getting `None`. PS: I am using Python 2.7

Comment: `sort` does not return the sorted list; it sorts it in-place. If you want it to return a new list, use `sorted` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite what you have to:

```
main_l = ['Temp_Farh', 'Surface', 'Heater_back', 'Front_Press', 'Lateral_Cels', 'Gauge_Finl','Gauge_Relay','Temp_Throw','Front_JL']
hlig = ['Temp', 'Lateral', 'Heater','Front']

found = [i for i in main_l if any(e in i for e in hlig)]
```

Then the solution is obvious:

```
not_found = [i for i in main_l if not any(e in i for e in hlig)]
answer = not_found + found
```

EDIT: Removed square brackets around list comprehension based on comments by Sven Marnach (to aviraldg's solution)

Comment: `if not any`   !!!! That was it!!! Oh that is frustrating! Thanks so much. This should have been how I did it. What I tried was to modify my approach to include `if e not in i`, but this gave a list that was much longer than `main_l` - obviously that was not working. Thanks again for showing the correct way to do it.

Comment: @WR The solution using sorting is faster, more concise and modifies the list in place, so you should consider it as well.

Comment: Agreed, but thanks for your post. It will help me with other scenarios.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, thanks for the suggestion to remove the brackets (even though it wasn't directed at my solution). Sorting may be faster when main_l is short enough, but at some point, as main_l grows, I expect sorting will be slower. Of course the sort is more elegant.

Comment: @jimhark I don't think it will be slower for any size.  The key function is evaluated only once for each element, and the actual sorting is performed on the returned key values.  There are only two possible key values, `False` and `True`, and for arrays with this property the Timsort algorithm used by Python's `list.sort()` method is essentially O(n).

Comment: @SvenMarnarch, Oh, you're right. Plus sort is in place so it's even better on memory. Nice.